# Stop UIImage flip for right to left languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, right-to-left

I added an `Image Set` to the `Asset Catalog` and set its `Direction` to `Left to Right, Mirrors`. I then added an `UIImageView` in my view controller and if the device's language is set to a right to left language, the image shows up flipped.

I would like for it not to flip in this case, as I'm manually managing the mother language inside the app. I tried setting the `UIImageView`'s `Semantic` to `Force Left-to-Right` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the following works:

Set the image set's direction to `Left to Right, Mirrors`.

[image: image set]

Force a specific direction for the `UIImageView`:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)setImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    _imageView = imageView;
    _imageView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
}
```

**Swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        imageView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

Now the image gets mirrored in an LTR environment as well as an RTL environment. If I set it to `.forceLeftToRight` instead the image does not get mirrored on any environment.

Comment: That is the default, so obviously it was `Fixed`. I would want for it to get mirrored only if I manually set the `semanticContentAttribute` to force right to left.

Comment: Ok. And it does not work if you set the image set's direction to `Left to Right, Mirrors` and the imageview's `semanticContentAttribute` to `.forceRightToLeft`?

Comment: No, not even if I set it to `.forceLeftToRight`. It looks like the os sets something similar to `semanticContentAttribute` directly to the `UIImageView`'s `UIImage`, and anything I set on `UIImageView` is ignored.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Indeed it works. My problem was that I had two images with arrows and they were being shown flipped, when the actual image views were flipped because I used leading constraints. So I had to also set force left to right on their superview.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152373/discussion-between-iulian-onofrei-and-andre-slotta).

Comment: So, for `UIButton`s, you need to use `self.myButton.imageView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight` in your `viewDidLoad` method in order for it to correctly work in all cases.

Comment: You might also need `[self.myButton layoutIfNeeded]` before setting its `imageView`'s `semanticContentAttribute` property.